# Implementation discrepancies between GNU Gzip and Python Gzip

Tags: python, compression, gzip, zlib

I am trying to use python's gzip package to perform a test of unzipping and rezipping a gzip'd archive (or any binary data) to better understand implementation differences between GNU gzip versions and Python's gzip.GzipFile. The use case is that I would like to inspect the contents of a compressed file and recompress it without changing the output.

One discrepancy I've noticed is that when compressing a file with two different gzip versions, the output is the same; however, when compressing it with gzip.GzipFile, the output changes.

For example...

Here, lzo-2.09.tar.gz has been compressed with one version of gzip and I am recompressing it using another.

```
joga:/tmp/gztest$ ls -l lzo*
-rw-r--r--@ 1 joga  wheel  594855 Dec 25 14:31 lzo-2.09.tar.gz
-rw-r--r--@ 1 joga  wheel  594855 Dec 25 14:38 lzo-2.09_copy.tar.gz
joga:/tmp/gztest$ gunzip lzo-2.09_copy.tar.gz
joga:/tmp/gztest$ cat lzo-2.09_copy.tar |gzip -9 >lzo-2.09_copy.tar.gz
joga:/tmp/gztest$ ls -l lzo*
-rw-r--r--@ 1 joga  wheel   594855 Dec 25 14:31 lzo-2.09.tar.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 joga  wheel   594855 Dec 25 14:39 lzo-2.09_copy.tar.gz
```

We see the output is the same (except for the timestamp.) Here is the corresponding python script:

```
import gzip
from StringIO import StringIO

with gzip.open('lzo-2.09.tar.gz', 'rb') as fh:
    lzo_bin = fh.read()

gzip_io = StringIO()
compressed_gzip = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=gzip_io, mode='wb', compresslevel=9)

with compressed_gzip as gzip_handle:
    gzip_handle.write(lzo_bin)

with open('lzo_py.tar.gz', 'wb') as fh:
    fh.write(gzip_io.getvalue())
```

And we see the result is different:

```
joga:/tmp/gztest$ ls -l lzo*
-rw-r--r--@ 1 joga  wheel   594855 Dec 25 14:31 lzo-2.09.tar.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 joga  wheel   594855 Dec 25 14:39 lzo-2.09_copy.tar.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 joga  wheel   595135 Dec 25 14:43 lzo_py.tar.gz
```

Here are the first several bytes in the two re-compressed files:

GNU Gzip:

```
00000000   1F 8B 08 00  00 00 00 00  02 FF 54 B7  63 8C 26 4C  D8 A6 DD B6  ..........T.c.&L....
```

Python GzipFile

```
00000000   1F 8B 08 00  00 00 00 00  02 FF EC 7D  7B 7B DB B6  F5 F0 EF DF  ...........}{{......
```

I understand that gzip/zlib makes no assurances that two copies of the same file, when compressed with different package versions, will yield the same result.  Empirically, however, I have observed that to be the case on many occasions.

My question is -- what is different about the Python implementation that might lead to this discrepancy? I have looked through the source code and could not find it myself, although admittedly I do not have a background in compression techniques or implementation.

Comment: must be 2 slightly different implementations to search for longest/most frequent strings. It doesn't change between different versions of gzip command. Have you tried with python 3? (you'll have to adapt your code)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Why do you think they're different implementations? Both should be using zlib. (The Python `gzip` module isn't a pure-Python implementation; that would be incredibly slow.)

Comment: okay rhen I'll leave you answer the question. I'm interested, keep me posted.

Comment: The `lzo_py.tar.gz` is shorter. Could it be the `compresslevel=9`?

Comment: @Gribouillis it is not the compression level. As you can see in the first example (GNU gzip,) I pass 9 as compression level there also.

Comment: It seems to me you fed `gzip_handle.write()` with the content of `lzo-2.09.tar.gz` . I think it should have been the content of `lzo-2.09.tar`.

Comment: `with open('lzo-2.09.tar.gz', 'rb') as fh:
    lzo_bin = fh.read()`

unpacks the gzip into the original tar.

Comment: No, it simply fetches the content of the `.tar.gz`.

Comment: @Gribouillis Apologies! Meant gzip.open(). That was a copypasta issue. The question still holds, however. I updated the question's lines of interest.

Comment: In order to make things very clear, can you add at test to compare the content of `lzo_bin` with the `lzo-2.09.tar`? If there is any difference in the input data, the result will be different.

Comment: Data is the same.

Comment: The gzip command comes with options `--name` and `--no-name` allowing to include or exclude the original file name in the gz. You could perhaps run gnu gzip with the --no-name option. [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip) also speaks about *optional extra headers* that may be present in the output. These headers could be different for python and gnu. You could compare if the tails of both results are the same.

Comment: Both headers are consistent with the RFC and dont have any extra flags set that would increase their length.

Comment: @Gribouillis The two examples shown have exactly the same gzip header. The difference is only in the compressed data.

Answer (score 2):

Python is using zlib, which has different compression code than gzip, though it was written by the same person, with the zlib code derived from the older gzip code. The results are generally different.

However, as you note, there is no assurance, and no need, for different compressors to be able to produce the same output from the same uncompressed input. All that is assured, and all that needs to be assured, is that when decompressed again, both produce exactly the original uncompressed input. This is the definition of lossless.

So how could it matter that the compressed data is different? Why do you care?

Comment: There is another way to produce gzipped file in python, via the `tarfile.open(mode = "w:gz", fileobj = fh)`. It may give a third different result. Also there are some modules im pypi such as gzippy, that might be worth exploring

Comment: Mark -- thanks answering my question. I am not thinking of this problem as a "compression" one, although maybe I should be. I am interested in cases where I modify a file very slightly without changing its size (say, 4 chars in a block of ASCII text, so the file entropy should remain ~ the same.) I would expect the zstream itself to be different but the overall compression ratio, or size of the compressed output blob, to be also ~ the same. But this is not always the case. What could be the cause of this? Buffer sizes in the implementation? Search algorithm differences?

Comment: I can't say without seeing an example, or without knowing what you mean by "~". In general, the fact that an unfounded expectation is not being met is due entirely to the unfounded expectation.